# Find a class with exactly specific students

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm no SQL expert, but I'm not a total amateur, yet this is a query on a single table with 2 fields that I don't know how to approach.

Suppose you have a table with class # & student #. How do you find the classes that have only exactly students x, y & z?

My real problem is more like a table of catalogs & item numbers, and how to find all the catalogs that have exactly (mo more or less) the specified items.

My only thought revolved around matching on GROUP_CONCAT, but there must b731e a more elegant way...

EDIT:
I misstated the problem, so I will provide table structure as well. The issue is more like products in boxes, where a box could contain more than one of a particular product, and you want to find boxes that have exactly the specified content. So the table, for example, is:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| box_id     | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_id | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to find all boxes that contain exactly 2 items of product ID 22, one of 17, and one of 55. No more, no less.

Comment: Will the x,y,z always be just three students, or could it be more like a,b,c,d,e,f,...,x,y,z where the number might vary for each query?

Comment: SHOW DESCRIBE TABLE `your tables please`

Comment: Yeah, could be any number of students, or any number of items in a bag. The point is to find any other "bag" in the table that has the exact same contents. It's a trivial concept, but a challenge to express it in SQL? For me, anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `having` clause:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
group by
        class
having  count(distinct student) = 3
        and max(case when student = 'X' then 1 end) = 1
        and max(case when student = 'Y' then 1 end) = 1
        and max(case when student = 'Z' then 1 end) = 1
```

Comment: Great idea to add the count() = N, but then, couldn't it be even simpler? Like, "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE student IN ('X','Y','Z") GROUP BY class HAVING count (DISTINCT student) = 3;"

Comment: @ChrisNY: In your query the `where` clause would filter out all other students, so it would match a class with student `W` as well.  And the question asks "only exactly students x, y & z"

Answer (score 0):

I do have an answer that works, but it is far from efficient OR elegant, so I present it for anyone looking for a sub-optimal but correct solution to this problem, and an enticement to anyone else to provide a better one.

```
SELECT box_id, GROUP_CONCAT( product_id
ORDER BY product_id DESC 
SEPARATOR  ',' ) AS contents
FROM box_product
GROUP BY box_id
HAVING contents =  '17,22,22,55';
```